# How to get data from Firebase FCM push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending out a push notification to:

`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

formatted as (in php):

```
   [
      'to' => $token,
      'data' => [
         'key' => $val
      ],
      'notification' => [
         'title' => $title,
         'body' => $message,
         'badge' => $badge,
         'sound' => 'default'
      ]
   ]
```

And my iOS app receives and displays the push perfectly, both foreground and background.  But I can't find how to access `data`

In my AppDelegate file I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

   let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as! JsonObject
   print(aps)
}
```

and the debug out from the `print` statement displays:

```
["sound": default, "badge": 1, "alert": {
    body = "One flew over the cuckoo's nest";
    title = "My Title";
}]
```

So where is my `data: {key:val}`  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data should be available directly on the `userInfo` dictionary, not on the "aps" key and you should be able to access it like this:

```
let customValue = userInfo["customKey"] as? String
```

As stated on the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive),

> The payload of notification messages is a dictionary of keys and values. Notification messages sent through APNs follow the APNs payload format as below:

```
{
    "aps" : {
      "alert" : {
        "body" : "great match!",
        "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      },
      "badge" : 1,
    },
    "customKey" : "customValue"
  }
```

Comment: Got the Firebase part but looked right past the fact that I was inside userInfo['aps']